# Allah's interference

Tags: quran

Salam,

Pls, don't misunderstand me.

My question/curiosity/doubt is:

Why Allah's interference is not present in the area of the war or the before the beginning of the war itself to save innocent's humans irrespective of their religion?

The other thing i feel there is no predestiny. Why would Allah allows these negative things or horrible?
to be written in one's life.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Allah is present everywhere and closer to everyone than their jugular vein. Even, there is not a single leaf that falls down anytime and He is not aware of it.

As far as your question regarding the presence of His interference in the war areas is concerned, we cant declare ourselves acquitted for whats going on around us as we are actually responsible for all this.

whereas “Allah Almighty said: O My servants, I have forbidden injustice for Myself and I have forbidden it among you, so do not oppress one another”
(sahih Muslim:2577)

And

“Allāh does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity. It will have [the consequence of] what [good] it has gained, and it will bear [the consequence of] what [evil] it has earned. “
(Al-Bakarah: 286).

“Then He inflicted upon you sorrows one after the other (for admonition and training)…… Allah is Well Aware of all your works.”

(Al imran:153).

So, negative thing or evil has an important role to play in advancing the spiritual development of an individual.

Comment: That's what i knew. But that's not the right or logical answer to my question.